# Is it safe to store user informations in the local storage?

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage

I have a small app, i begin with IONIC and for the moment i store the token in the local storage. For the user informations (such as first name, last name or avatar for instance), how can i get that ? Should i make only one call and save those informations as an object in the local storage ? Or otherwise make a function which can get these informations when i need rather than saving that in a local storage ?

The main question is, is it safe to store user informations in a local storage ?

Answer (score 3):

In general you could rely on localStorage with a Cordova app: in fact it is under the Cordova/app sandbox.

Some details and alternative (on iOS) are in this post:

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/securing-phonegapcordova-hybrid-mobile-app/

Another alternative is to use some plugin like the following:

https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage